# Is there any way to know if kafka message has been confirmed in Producer?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

In Spring boot project, I used spring-kafka.

How to implement the following functions ?

Consumer:

```
   @KafkaListener
    public void listenChatGroup1(Acknowledgment ack) {

        doWork();
        //finished ! And notfiy producer 
        ack.acknowledge();
    }
```

producer :

```
kafkaTemplate.send("",new CallBack(){

  public void onConsumerAcknowledge(){
    //Is there a similar way implementation this function?

  }
});
```

Comment: Apache Kafka is a message queue that decouples the producer side from the consumer side. It does not provide a mechanism for producers to directly interact with consumer.

Answer (score 0):

First, `KafkaTemplate.send` returns a Future, which you'd need to get. It doesn't accept a callback parameter.

Assuming separate applications, you'd need to make your "producer" also into a "consumer" and vice-versa in order to "notify" any producer that that message had been consumed.

One higher level framework to do this is [Spring Cloud Bus](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-bus/reference/html/)

---

If you're in the same application, you could use a simple callback interface, or use `@EventListener` consumer methods and an `ApplicationEventPublisher` class to notify it

---

Or your consumer and producer could write/query a shared database that says what records have been sent or processed.

Either way, it's up to you to introduce coupling between your clients because Kafka is designed for them to completely decoupled.

Comment: Or you can do a request - reply pattern : https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#replying-template

Comment: `>It doesn't accept a callback parameter.` It supports a callback, but in a different way; `KafkaTemplate` returns a `ListenableFuture` with `onSuccess` and `onFailure` callbacks. https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#sending-messages

Comment: @GaryRussell Like I said, they need to get/assign the Future in order to use it

Comment: Right but `get()` is sync; if they want an async callback, they need to add a listener to the future returned by `send()`.